# Переключение языка с cookie

Tags: jquery, cookie

Есть такой простой скрипт и библиотека cookie. Как сделать,чтобы скрипт запоминал, какой язык был выбран даже после перезагрузки или перехода на другую страницу сайта?

```js
 $(function(){
 $("#en-sw").click(function(){
    jQuery('#fr-sw').removeClass("active");
    jQuery('#en-sw').addClass("active"); 
 jQuery('.fr').hide(); 
 jQuery('.en').show();  
 
  });
  
  $("#fr-sw").click(function(){
    jQuery('#en-sw').removeClass("active");
    jQuery('#fr-sw').addClass("active"); 
 jQuery('.en').hide(); 
 jQuery('.fr').show();  
 
  });
 });


/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2006, 2014 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD (Register as an anonymous module)
  define(['jquery'], factory);
 } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
  // Node/CommonJS
  module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
 } else {
  // Browser globals
  factory(jQuery);
 }
}(function ($) {

 var pluses = /\+/g;

 function encode(s) {
  return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
 }

 function decode(s) {
  return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
 }

 function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
  return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
 }

 function parseCookieValue(s) {
  if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
   // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
   s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
  }

  try {
   // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
   // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
   // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
   s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
   return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
  } catch(e) {}
 }

 function read(s, converter) {
  var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
  return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
 }

 var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

  // Write

  if (arguments.length > 1 && !$.isFunction(value)) {
   options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

   if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
    var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
    t.setMilliseconds(t.getMilliseconds() + days * 864e+5);
   }

   return (document.cookie = [
    encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
    options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
    options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
    options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
    options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
   ].join(''));
  }

  // Read

  var result = key ? undefined : {},
   // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
   // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
   // calling $.cookie().
   cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [],
   i = 0,
   l = cookies.length;

  for (; i < l; i++) {
   var parts = cookies[i].split('='),
    name = decode(parts.shift()),
    cookie = parts.join('=');

   if (key === name) {
    // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
    result = read(cookie, value);
    break;
   }

   // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
   if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
    result[name] = cookie;
   }
  }

  return result;
 };

 config.defaults = {};

 $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
  // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
  $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
  return !$.cookie(key);
 };

}));
```

```css
#fr-sw.active {font-weight:bold}
#en-sw.active {font-weight:bold}
.fr {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="en-sw" class="active">Eng</a>
<a id="fr-sw">Fr</a>

<div class="en">на Английском</div>
<div class="fr" style="display:none;">на Французском</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал не использовать плагин для хранения данных на клиенте, вместо этого использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
Вот пример кода:

```js
  $(function() {
      var choosenLang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'fr';
      $('#' + choosenLang + '-sw').addClass('active');
      $('.' + choosenLang).show();
      $('.lang').on('click', function () {
          $('.active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var lang = $(this).data('lang');
          $('.lang-div').hide();
          $('.' + lang).show();
         localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
      });
  });
```

```css
   #fr-sw.active {font-weight:bold}
   #en-sw.active {font-weight:bold}
   .fr, .en {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="en-sw" class="lang" data-lang="en">Eng</a>
  <a id="fr-sw" class="lang"  data-lang="fr">Fr</a>

  <div class="en lang-div">на Английском</div>
  <div class="fr lang-div">на Французском</div>
```

Comment: Хм, ваш пример не работает на сайте. Т.е. он переключает,но не запоминает выбор. И по умолчанию французский активен

Comment: я немного исправил код, должно работать так как должно

Comment: Супер! Теперь работает! Спасибо огромное!